Symfony htmlTemplate doesn't work in production
Following is the email send code
$email = (new TemplatedEmail())
->from('info@example.com')
->to($applicantEmail)
->subject('Congratulations! Application Successful')
->htmlTemplate('main/email/admission_mail.html.twig')
->context(['name' => $name])
;
$mailer->send($email);

This code works fine in localhost without any issue but in production, I'm using hostinger shared host I am getting following error:

Unable to find template "main/email/admission_mail.html.twig" (looked
into: /home/u511184722/domains/example.com/public_html/templates,
/home/u511184722/domains/example.com/public_html/vendor/symfony/twig-bridge/Resources/views/Form).

How to resolve this
for an alternative I used
$email = (new Email())
    ->html($this->renderView('email/email.html.twig', [
        'name' => 'John Doe',
    ]));

I'm getting following error
Unable to find template "main/email/admission_mail.html.twig" (looked into: C:\wamp64\www\cin_cms/templates, C:\wamp64\www\cin_cms\vendor\symfony\twig-bridge/Resources/views/Form).


Do your templates live in a folder called templates in the root directory of you project? That's what /home/u511184722/domains/example.com/public_html/templates appears to be looking for.

@ChrisHaas inside templates\main\email

Did you check on the server if your template file really exists ?
And do your webserver user have the right to read the templates folder ?

I made a stupid typo by mistake while pushing to prod.
